# I made my launcher, I want the launcher to manually display application icons, visible or invisible

Tags: android

I made my launcher, I want the launcher to manually display application icons, visible or invisible.

I can’t hide the icons of the selected application right now. Now I select several applications to hide, but they are still not hidden on the menu.

```
private class HideAppsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<App> {
    private HideAppsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<App> adapterArrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_hide_apps, adapterArrayList);
    }

    @NonNull
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.item_hide_apps, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder._apkIcon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.IVappIcon);
            holder._apkName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVappName);
            holder._apkPackage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVappPackage);
            holder._checker = convertView.findViewById(R.id.CBappSelect);
            holder._switcherChecked = convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcherChecked);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Misha. Welcome to StackOverflow :) It's not clear what your issue is. Could you please update your question to explain your desired result and what is wrong now.

Comment: I can’t hide the icons of the selected application right now. Now I select several applications to hide, but they are still not hidden on the menu

Comment: I'm guessing your code above is for a ListView to select which apps should be visible. You don't seem to have any data (eg. a list of apps), or a menu. Can you share the rest of the code? And perhaps screenshot(s) of your app?

Comment: I will send the full package if you tell me the mail

Comment: Please just post all relevant information in your question.

Comment: here is the link where I downloaded https://github.com/OpenLauncherTeam/openlauncher